# PHP class constructor argument provided by the client soap

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, soap-client, soapserver

I have a bunch of SOAP servers serving a php class and a client accessing those servers. The served php class makes connection to a local database and this connection is setup in the construtor method.

I saw you can set arguments to the constructor in the server side:

```
$server = new SoapServer($wsdlFile);
$server->setClass('Class', $arg);
```

Is there a way to the client provide the argument to the class constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way but , first are you using any soap library for the php like NuSoap , zendsoap or something like that?

on Nusoap you get the methods and after that you can resend that information to the database.

Comment: I'm using PHP's internal libraries (classes) SoapServer and SoapClient.

Comment: I don't have a problem getting the methods declared in the wsdl file, however i've didn't find a way to pass arguments to the __construct method...